# What is wrong with my URL and _POST?

Tags: php, forms, url

For some reason I can't get this to work. It pulls the name and team but not the other data.

Here is my _POST data:
        $id=$_GET['name'];
    $tm=$_GET['team'];
    $hr=$_POST['hours'];
    $bl = $_POST['block'];
    $sp = $_POST['spec_area'];
    $wx = $_POST['wx'];

Here is my URL:

```
<a href="ola_admin.php?  name='.$data["name"].'&web='.$data["webex"].'&team='.$data['team'] .'&hr='.$data['hours'] .'">update</a></td>
```

And here is where I am trying to put it (testing only of course):

```
<?php
  echo $tm;
  echo $wx;
  echo $hours;
  echo $hr;
?>
```

So when I click the link obviously I want it to post the data... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `name` and `team` are received via GET and not post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the data via the URL in the way you are, it can only be retrieved with `$_GET`. The `$_POST` array is for data submitted in a `<form>` tag.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are passing variables via `GET` request, but you're trying to retreive some of them via `$_POST`, just change them all to `$_GET`:

```
$id = $_GET['name'];
$tm = $_GET['team'];
$hr = $_GET['hours'];
$bl = $_GET['block'];
$sp = $_GET['spec_area'];
$wx = $_GET['wx'];
```

If you want to use `$_POST` then you need to send data through `<form>` with `method="POST"`.

[PHP Manual: Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

You should also be aware, that using it this way leads to XSS vulnerabilities.